# Airflow in Kubernetes: airflow variables not seen in operators

Tags: kubernetes, airflow, kubernetes-helm

I have Airflow deployed on kubernetes cluster (via helm) and with `KubernetesExecutor` selected.

In Airflow Web UI (at Admin -> Variables section) I see some Airflow variables set.

I'm trying to access these variables from Python code inside my `PythonVirtualenvOperator` (airflow is also installed as one of its pip dependencies).

I call `Variable.get('MY_SUPER_DOOPER_VAR')` and get an error:

`KeyError: Variable MY_SUPER_DOOPER_VAR does not exist`.

What should I do to pass airflow variables inside my operators?